# Запрос к базе данных LARAVEL

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Всем привет, уважаемые программисты)
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Необходимо правильно составить запрос к БД.

1. таблица shops (магазин)
   id,
2. таблица shop_map_point (точку на карте, у каждого магазина может быть несколько точек)
   id, city_id
3. таблица products (товар)
   id, shop_id, category_id
4. таблица categories (категория)
   id,
5. city (города)
   id,

Мы находимся в категории id = 5, в городе id = 10
Нужно выбрать все товары, у которых

- МАГАЗИН имеет ТОЧКУ НА КАРТЕ (city_id = 10)
- У этих МАГАЗИНОВ есть ТОВАР в этой КАТЕГОРИИ (category_id = 5)

- использовать лен.загрузку к товару (чтобы потом при foriech к товару без лишних запросов можно было добавить название магазина) ->with()

Заранее благодарен.
Нужно ли использовать джойны или без них можно обойтись?

Comment: Сформулируйте как-то иначе. Не понятно совсем какие таблицы есть и какие у них столбцы. Вероятно тут нужны relationships для построения запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product::where('category_id', 5)
->whereHas('shops', function ($query) {
    $query ->whereHas('mapPoints', function ($query) {
       $query->where('city_id', 10);
    });})->with(...)->get();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]